# save the color of a text in a database and copy text with color into a richtextbox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, colors, richtextbox

I want to maintain the format of a text when i copy it into a `richtextbox`, How can i do this? 
(When you copy code in a microsoft word document, the color of the code will be the same as in Visual studio (show here http://img4.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenannta2k46fcjn5.png ))

And i want to save the text in a sql database and reload it with the same format(colors, etc.). I know how to save and read data in a database but how can i save the text with the format(color)?

Answer (score 2):

you could also save the FlowDocument which is hiden in `RichTextBox.Document` as string

```
public static string ToStringExt(this IDocumentPaginatorSource flowDocument)
{
    return XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument);
}
```

to convert it back as FlowDocument you can use this extensions

```
public static bool IsFlowDocument(this string xamlString)
{
    if (xamlString.IsNullOrEmpty()) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (xamlString.StartsWith("<") && xamlString.EndsWith(">"))
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            xml.LoadXml(string.Format("<Root>{0}</Root>", xamlString));
            return true;
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static FlowDocument toFlowDocument(this string xamlString)
{
    if (IsFlowDocument(xamlString))
    {
        var stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
        var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;
    }
    else
    {
        Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
        myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(xamlString));
        FlowDocument myFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        myFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

        return myFlowDocument;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do all this when you can just use the `Rtf` property?

Comment: @Svish because `Rtf` is `System.Windows.Forms` and doesn't exist in `Wpf` :O)

Comment: Ah. WPF seems complicated :p

Comment: @Svish if you still know a better solution, it would be nice if you share it with use :o)

Comment: Never managed to get started with WPF, so I don't have anything to share :) (overlooked the WPF tag on the question)

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Rtf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) property of the RichTextBox

`richtextbox1.Rtf` => Store to database

Retrieve from database and restore value in `richtextbox1.Rtf`.