# Convert a Flowdocument to XML and XML to Flowdocument

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, converters, flowdocument

I use the Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547738/save-the-color-of-a-text-in-a-database-and-copy-text-with-color-into-a-richtextb)(Answer from Wiimax) to convert my `FlowDocument` to `XML` and convert it back to `FlowDocument`. But now i have some Problems here.

My Code for the convert:

```
public static bool IsFlowDocument(this string xamlString)
        {
            if (xamlString == null || xamlString == "")
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            if (xamlString.StartsWith("<") && xamlString.EndsWith(">"))
            {
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                try
                {
                    xml.LoadXml(string.Format("<Root>{0}</Root>", xamlString));
                    return true;
                }
                catch (XmlException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static FlowDocument toFlowDocument(this string xamlString)
        {
            if (IsFlowDocument(xamlString))
            {
                var stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
                var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

                return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;
            }
            else
            {
                Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
                myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(xamlString));
                FlowDocument myFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();
                myFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

                return myFlowDocument;
            }
        }
```

I enter this code(as example, its not the code, which i use in my program):

[image: My code]

And after convert i get back this code:

[image: My code]

You see that some blank were skipped. And after the namespace there was add a { }
I looked at the converted XML String, there are no blank skipped, but the { } is their to

Do someone know how to fix that or see a fail from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*curly Braces:*

this is because of Binding-Syntax and WPF (Xamlreader and XamlWriter) wants to help you ;).

When in your XAML-Code is something like

```
<Run Text="{" />
```

the Xaml-Engine first assumes a binding. Since there is no and depending on how you create your FlowDocument the **'{'** is Escaped to **'{}{'**

One Workaround is, that you put your curly brace like this:

```
<Run>{</Run>
```

another workaround is to avoid that  the curly brace is the first character:

```
<Run Text=" {" />
```

*spaces:*
There is an attribute which comes in handy:

```
<Run xml:space="preserve">some                   Space</Run>
```

this isn't a Xaml but an XML attribute which is handled by the Xaml-Engine.